# jQuery UI autocomplete store the selected items ID in input's value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on a dynamic time sheet. My project field is using jQuery autocomplete which pulls its data from a json file. Once an item has been selected from autocomplete, I'm trying to set the `value=""` of the input field to the `id` of the selected item.

My json file contents is like this

```
{
  "projectList": [{
    "label": "Some Project",
    "id": "BP1927",
    "desc": "desc1"
  }, {
    "label": "Some Other Project",
    "id": "BP1827",
    "desc": "desc1"
  }, {
    "label": "BOSS Support",
    "id": "BP6354",
    "desc": "desc3"
  }, {
    "label": "Another Support",
    "id": "BP2735"
  }]
}
```

What I want to do is when I select the first item **Some Project**, I want to show Some Project in the input-box and store the ID **"BP1927"** in the value attribute of the input-box.

With my current code, my autocomplete will return project label to the input box, but when I inspect the input element, it will always show the `value` as being "BP2735"- which happens to be the last object within the json file. What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var rowTemplate = $('table.tablesubmit>tbody>tr:first').remove();

  var autoComp = {
    source: function(request, response) {
      var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
      response($.map(myJSONdata.projectList, function(item) {
        if (regex.test(item.id) || regex.test(item.label)) {
          return {
            label: item.label,
            value: item.label,
            id: item.id
          };
        }
        $("#project").attr("value", item.id);
      }));
    }
  };

  $('.pluslink').click(function(event) {
    var newRow = rowTemplate.clone();
    newRow.find('input:first').autocomplete(autoComp);
    $('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);
  });

  $("table.tablesubmit").on('click', '.minuslink', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

  $('.pluslink').click(); //Creates the first row
});

var myJSONdata = {
  "projectList": [{
    "label": "Some Project",
    "id": "BP1927",
    "desc": "desc1"
  }, {
    "label": "Some Other Project",
    "id": "BP1827",
    "desc": "desc1"
  }, {
    "label": "BOSS Support",
    "id": "BP6354",
    "desc": "desc3"
  }, {
    "label": "Another Support",
    "id": "BP2735"
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table class="tablesubmit">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Project name</th>
      <th width="10%">Mon</th>
      <th width="10%">Tue</th>
      <th width="10%">Wed</th>
      <th width="10%">Thur</th>
      <th width="10%">Fri</th>
      <th width="10%">Sat</th>
      <th width="10%">Sun</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="project" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1.25">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5.5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger minuslink">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold" width="25%">
        <a>Total Time:</a>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.25" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="8" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.5" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td>37.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary pluslink">Add new project</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer as per chat discussion with OP**

The problem is that you are trying to set the attribute when the suggestion list is being generated.

```
   source: function(request, response) {
      var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
      response($.map(myJSONdata.projectList, function(item) {
        if (regex.test(item.id) || regex.test(item.label)) {
          return {
            label: item.label,
            value: item.label,
            id: item.id
          };
        }
        $("#project").attr("value", item.id);
      }));
    }
```

So when the suggestion list is being generated every item is putting it's id in the value attribute and thus you are seeing the last items id while inspecting the element afterwards.

You have to set the value when a suggestion is selected, when when the suggestion list is being generated. The correct way to do this is to pass a input change event handler to autocomplete, that will set your attribute whenever a suggestion is selected.

```
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.item){ //this checks if any value is selected
            $(event.target).attr('value',ui.item.id);
        }
    },
```

Jquery UI autocomplete [change event documentation.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var rowTemplate = $('table.tablesubmit>tbody>tr:first').remove();

  var autoComp = {
    change: function(event, ui) {
     if(ui.item)$(event.target).attr('value',ui.item.id);
    },
    source: function(request, response) {
      var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');
      response($.map(myJSONdata.projectList, function(item) {
        if (regex.test(item.id) || regex.test(item.label)) {
          return {
            label: item.label,
            value: item.label,
            id: item.id
          };
        }
        $("#project").attr("value", item.id);
      }));
    }
  };

  $('.pluslink').click(function(event) {
    var newRow = rowTemplate.clone();
    newRow.find('input:first').autocomplete(autoComp);
    $('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);
  });

  $("table.tablesubmit").on('click', '.minuslink', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

  $('.pluslink').click(); //Creates the first row
});

var myJSONdata = {
  "projectList": [{
    "label": "Some Project",
    "id": "BP1927",
    "desc": "desc1"
  }, {
    "label": "Some Other Project",
    "id": "BP1827",
    "desc": "desc1"
  }, {
    "label": "BOSS Support",
    "id": "BP6354",
    "desc": "desc3"
  }, {
    "label": "Another Support",
    "id": "BP2735"
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<table class="tablesubmit">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Project name</th>
      <th width="10%">Mon</th>
      <th width="10%">Tue</th>
      <th width="10%">Wed</th>
      <th width="10%">Thur</th>
      <th width="10%">Fri</th>
      <th width="10%">Sat</th>
      <th width="10%">Sun</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="project" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1.25">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5.5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger minuslink">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold" width="25%">
        <a>Total Time:</a>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.25" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="8" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.5" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td>37.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary pluslink">Add new project</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.  It hasn't resolved my issue. Do I need to change the to use value instead of id?

Comment: My issue is that I can't set the `$("#project").attr("value", item.label);`  - it will always take the last object within the json file

Comment: Yes you need to change it to value, and delete the line you just said, that line can do nothing, trust me. Try it.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested.  It still doesn't work. I haven't changed anything inside my json file, does anything need changed?  The whole point behind mu question is to get my HTML value attribute to show the JSON id value.

Comment: I have updated my question, please see if that makes more sense.  I have implemented your changes and it still doesn't work.  Thanks :)

Comment: It works when you implement the changes, I have added the JSFIddle link above.

Comment: The upper part of the JSFiddle is just to make the ajax call work in Fiddle. I only changed id->value, and added _$('#project').autocomplete(autoComp);_ at the bottom of the script.

Comment: If you create a new row in the fiddle, set a value, then inspect the input box in developer console you will see it doesn't have a value="" tag - the purpose of my question is to figure out how I set the value to whatever has been returned to the autocomplete.  Hence using `$("#project").attr("value", item.label);` in my code.  I think you are misunderstanding me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164626/discussion-between-munim-munna-and-xoog).